# AttributeError when using the find() method

Tags: python

Hoping someone can provide an explanation for this...

I'm new to Python and stumbled across this working on an assignment (learning via online course):

Created card deck and need to remove several cards -- thought I'd .find(str) in the deck[], return it's index (i) and .remove(i). This way I can validate how the code is working since I'm still learning...

When I use the .find() method, I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'`

But no such error on the index method:  Here are the two methods.

`

```
def indxcard(self,fcard):
    '''

    :return index of -1 if not found

    '''
    retval=-1

    try:
        retval=self.Carddeck.index(fcard)

    except:
        # value not found
        retval = -1

    # print only for debugging
    print('in Indxcard', retval,fcard)
    return retval

def findcard(self, fcard):
    '''
    :return index of card -1 if not found

    '''
    retval = self.Carddeck.find(fcard)  # Causes an attribute error...
    print('in find card', retval, fcard)
    return retval
```

... and the calling code...

```
print(gamedeck)
print('-----------')
for killzerocard in Cards.Suits:
    # gamedeck.killcard('0'+killzerocard[1:])  # Uno deck only as 1  Zero (0) card for each of the colors

    try:
        gamedeck.findcard('0'+killzerocard)
    except:
        print('error thrown by find')

    gamedeck.indxcard('0'+killzerocard)

print('-----------')

# gamedeck.shuffle()
print(gamedeck)
```

`

and the results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` objects don't have a `find` method. Both `str` and `list` objects have a `index` method, but only `str` has the `find` method. With strings, the two methods are largely similar, except that when the argument is not present in the string, `index` will throw an exception, and `find` will return `-1`.

Comment: Thanks @mypetition -- figured it was something obvious (more or less).